# How can you update an Analysis Services tabular model with the changes in the data source?

Tags: ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

After defining a model in a SQL Server Analysis Services Tabular project, the schema in an underlying data source may change. These changes are not automatically detected or updated in a project.

With multidimensional projects you can open the DataSource View right click on "refresh" to get the updates. However, I don't see similar functionality in tabular projects.

How can you update an Analysis Services tabular model with the changes in the data source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps to update the model after the underlying database changes:

1. Right click on a table and select Table 'Properties...'
2. Click the 'Design...' button
3. Click on the 'Query' menu
4. Click 'Refresh Current'

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For SSAS Tabular and Azure Analysis Services, for updates to the underlying schema, you have to go to the 'Table Menu' & Table Properties and edit the [table properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/gg492147(v=sql.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). If you then click the refresh preview it will detect the changes and show the new columns. You have to select the tick boxes, to bring newly added columns to the main Tabular Model. You have to do this for all table, there isn't a full detect all changes option.

Question on msdn for reference [More info here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5d406d3f-03c5-4d51-a16b-80440d1fa00e/update-tabular-model-when-the-underlying-relational-database-schema-changes?forum=sqlanalysisservices)